# Style the td of a checked p:selectOneRadio item

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 7.

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="time" value="AM" columns="2"
                  unselectable="true" rendered="true" styleClass="label"
                  layout="lineDirection" enabledClass="radio-active">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="AM" itemValue="AM" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="PM" itemValue="PM"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

I need style the `td` in which the radio button is situated on its check event.

[image]

Comment: You said you want to style it - what exactly you want? Do you want to change the color of the TD, increase its size, change the text color??

Comment: Hi Rohan,
 what I need is that when I checked AM i have to style the TD with some colors and styles.

Comment: A component which suits your needs more closely is https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputSwitch.xhtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery for adding the CSS classes to the `td` elements:

```html
    <script>
            function changeSelection(){
                jQuery("#time td").removeClass('checked-td'); // remove the 'checked-td' from both td elements
                jQuery("#time input:checked").parents('td').last().addClass('checked-td'); // adding 'checked-td' class
            }
    </script>
```

`changeSelection` JS function needs to be executed on the selection change:

```
    <p:selectOneRadio id="time" value="AM" columns="2"
                      unselectable="true" rendered="true" styleClass="label"
                      onchange="changeSelection();"
                      layout="lineDirection" enabledClass="radio-active">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="AM" itemValue="AM" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="PM" itemValue="PM"/>

    </p:selectOneRadio>
```

Then you will be able to specify styles for  `checked-td` class. E.g.:

```html
    <style>
        .checked-td {
            background: brown;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: OP wants to style the cell based on the checked state of the buttons

Comment: Right. I've modified the answer. Thank you.